# electron-builder Windows -- method to make window Icon different from taskbar icon

Tags: electron, electron-builder

For Production Windows builds, is there any way in `electron-builder` to make the window top icon (e.g. the icon in the same strata as the "X") different from the Windows taskbar icon? It seems that only `icon:` in `election-builder.yml` is the only configurable option.